# How to check and get Alexa slot value with Python ask sdk

Tags: python, alexa-skills-kit, alexa-slot, alexa-sdk-python

In my interaction model I defined a slot named `city` that is optional, not required, to fulfill an intent.

I'm using the python ask sdk, so my handler is this:

```
class IntentHandler(RequestHandler):
    """
    Intent handler
    """

    def can_handle(self, handler_input):
        # type: (HandlerInput) -> bool
        return is_request_type("IntentRequest")(handler_input) and \
               is_intent_name("ExampleIntent")(handler_input)

    def handle(self, handler_input):
        # type: (HandlerInput) -> Response
        access_token = handler_input.request_envelope.context.system.user.access_token

        if access_token is None:
            raise Exception("no access_token provided")

        speech = RESPONSE_MESSAGE_DEFAULT
        handler_input.response_builder.speak(speech)

    return handler_input.response_builder.response
```

How can I check if the slot was filled by the user and how can I get its value?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In your handler, you can do something like this:

```
slots = handler_input.request_envelope.request.intent.slots
city = slots['city']
if city.value:
    # take me down to the paradise city
else:
    # this city was not built on rock'n'roll
```

`slots` is a dictionary of `str: Slot` values, see the source code for [Intent](https://github.com/alexa/alexa-apis-for-python/blob/master/ask-sdk-model/ask_sdk_model/intent.py) and [Slot](https://github.com/alexa/alexa-apis-for-python/blob/master/ask-sdk-model/ask_sdk_model/slot.py) for more details.

Comment: for my use case, using the built in animal slot, I have something like this working : 
```python 
{'animal': {
     'confirmation_status': 'NONE', 
     'name': 'animal', 
     'resolutions': None, 
     'value': 'a dog'}
}
```

Then I access this data by doing : 
```python
slots = handler_input.request_envelope.request.intent.slots
        print(slots)
        animal_slot = slots['animal']
        animal = animal_slot.value
        print(f"ANIMAL REQUESTED: {animal}")
```

Answer (score 4):

Per the docs found [here](https://alexa-skills-kit-python-sdk.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/core.html#ask_sdk_core.utils.request_util.get_slot), you could do something like this:

```
import ask_sdk_core.utils as ask_utils
slot = ask_utils.request_util.get_slot(handler_input, "slot_name")
if slot.value:
    # do stuff
```